# Display barplot in column order using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame with two columns - col1 and col2, but when I use `df.plot.barh`, the plot returns results in col2 and col1 order. Is there a way to get the plot to display results in col1 and col2 order?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(5,2)), columns=['col1','col2'])
df.plot.barh()
```

will yield this:

[image]

Instead using bar():

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(5,2)), columns=['col1','col2'])
df.plot.bar()
```

[image]

In both instances, col1 is first in that it is closest to the x axis. To reverse the order of the columns, you would need to reverse the order in which they appear in your dataframe. For just two columns you can use:

```
df = df[df.columns[::-1]]
```